# using a nested if statement within a for loop

Tags: python, string, iteration

i'm trying to read through a string (with no spaces) pull out instances where there is a single lowercase letter surrounded on both sides by 3 upper cases (i.e. HHSkSIO). I've written the code below:

```
def window(fseq, window_size=7):
    for i in xrange(len(fseq) - window_size + 1):
        yield fseq[i:i+window_size]


for seq in window('asjdjdfkjdhfkdjhsdfkjsdHJJnJSSsdjkdsad', 7):
    if seq[0].isupper and seq[1].isupper and seq[2].isupper and seq[3].islower and seq[4].isupper and seq[5].isupper and seq[6].isupper:
            print seq
```

where the first function window allows me to iterate through the string using a sliding window of 7 and the second part, the for statement, checks whether the characters within each window are higher higher higher lower higher higher higher. When I run the code, it comes out with:

```
asjdjdf
sjdjdfk
jdjdfkj
djdfkjd
jdfkjdh
dfkjdhf
fkjdhfk
kjdhfkd
jdhfkdj
dhfkdjh
hfkdjhs
fkdjhsd
kdjhsdf
djhsdfk
jhsdfkj
hsdfkjs
sdfkjsd
dfkjsdH
fkjsdHJ
kjsdHJJ
jsdHJJn
sdHJJnJ
dHJJnJs
HJJnJsd
JJnJsdj
JnJsdjk
nJsdjkd
Jsdjkds
sdjkdsa
djkdsad
```

How can I make the for statement **only** print out the sliding window which conforms to the above if statement, rather than printing out all of them? P.S i know this is probably a very clunky way of doing it, I'm a beginner and it was the only thing i could think of!

Comment: `seq[0].isupper` and the rest don't actually call the functions. A method object is "truthy", hence your condition is always `True`. You could also save yourself some trouble and use the fact that `str.isupper` returns `True` if all cased characters in a string are upper.

Comment: ah OK, so I need: if seq[0] == True ?

Comment: No, you need to call the methods, for example `seq[:3].isupper()` would test if the 2 first characters are cased characters and uppercase. In general you never do `something == True` in python. Just test for `something`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `isupper` and `islower` methods:

```
    if seq[:3].isupper() and seq[3].islower() and seq[4:].isupper():
        print seq
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are missing the () in your calls to .isupper, which always evaluate to true.

Try:

```
def window(fseq, window_size=7):
    for i in range(len(fseq) - window_size + 1):
        yield fseq[i:i+window_size]


for seq in window('asjdjdfkjdhfkdjhsdfkjsdHJJnJSSsdjkdsad', 7):
    if seq[0].isupper() and seq[1].isupper() and seq[2].isupper() and seq[3].islower() and seq[4].isupper() and seq[5].isupper() and seq[6].isupper():
        print (seq)
```

The other way of doing it, would be:

```
import re
s = re.compile(r'[A-Z]{3}[a-z][A-Z]{3}')
def window(fseq, window_size=7):
    for i in range(len(fseq) - window_size + 1):
        yield fseq[i:i+window_size]

for seq in window('asjdjdfkjdhfkdjhsdfkjsdHJJnJSSsdjkdsad', 7):
    result = s.search(seq)
    if result is not None:
        print(result.group())
```